# Lazy fetch not work for OneToOne relation in EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

in my project I used **EclipseLink** as the JPA implementation. And I have two entities, Product and ProductDetail:

- They have one-to-one relation. One Product should have only one ProductDetail.
- ProductDetail could not be null. One Product should always has ProductDetail.
- The relation is unidirection. I will only access ProductDetail from Product.
- The two entities should have shared primary key, the "id" of a Product should be equal to "prodId" of the ProductDetail.

So I designed the entity models like following:

```
@Table(name="product")
public class Product{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "PRODUCT_ID")
    @UuidGenerator(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    @Column(name = "id", unique=true, nullable=false, length=200)
    private String id;

    // Some other properties....

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private ProductDetail productDetail;
}
```

---

```
@Table(name="product_detail")
public class ProductDetail{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "prod_id", unique=true, nullable=false, length=200)
    private String prodId;

    // Some other properties....
}
```

But the lazy fetching never worked. The ProductDetail is always fetched with the Product. I checked many documents but still cannot figure it out. Does anyone have some experience on this? Thanks a lot!

**NOTICE**: I'm using EclipseLink but not Hibernate.

Comment: FYI LAZY fetch mode is a HINT to the JPA provider only, not something mandatory that a JPA provider must obey. I know that DataNucleus JPA follows what the user sets, but no idea about EclipseLink

Comment: You need to configure weaving to enable lazy loading on toOne mappings. What's your runtime environment?

Comment: And how are you checking that OneToOne is always fetched - just accessing it to check will cause it to be fetched.  Why do you have that PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation on your OneToOne mapping with a UuidGenerator on the id string field?  One or the other should set the DB field - you should look into the JPA mapsId annotation instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make lazy loading on toOne relationships work EclipseLink must inject a proxy into the reference. This process is called "weaving".

This is not enabled by default so you have to check out the documentation how to enable weaving for your runtime environment:

https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/solutions/testingjpa004.htm#CHDEECDB